# No commands defined in the auth namespace on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to implement a remind/reset password on a Laravel application, using the [official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#password-reminders-and-reset)

On the step of running:

```
php artisan auth:reminders
```

I'm getting the error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "auth" namespace.
```

Does anyone know how to properly configure it?

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you running? To find out - type `php artisan --version`

Comment: What happens if you run `php artisan auth:reminders-table`?

Comment: The same InvalidArgumentException

Comment: Did you upgrade the application from an older version? Or is this a fresh install?

Comment: I had 4.2.8 and run composer installer to upgrade, is it considered an upgrade or it makes a fresh install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your /config/app/config.php is probably missing the Reminders service provider. Add this to your array of providers.

```
'providers' => array(
    ...
    'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
    ....
)
```

Comment: That's it!! I had it commented, don't know why... ;)

Comment: I had the same problem myself, and finding this thread is what helped me solve it. So thanks for asking!